# CSS3 Vibrate animation without using margin

Tags: css

I have a set of 6 strings that I want to vibrate when I hover over them. To do this i'm using keyframe on the margin as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/A4nBv/1/

The problem is that changing the margin, for example on the top string when hovered over, pushed the rest of the strings down, givng the appearance that all strings are vibrating. I only need the one string to vibrate, can anyone think of a solution using just css?

```
<div class="strings">
    <div class="string" id="stringHighE"></div>
    <div class="string" id="stringB"></div>
    <div class="string" id="stringG"></div>
    <div class="string" id="stringD"></div>
    <div class="string" id="stringA"></div>
    <div class="string" id="stringLowE"></div>
</div>

body, html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

}.strings {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.string {
    height:2%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    background: black;
}
#stringLowE:hover, #stringA:hover, #stringDhover, #stringG:hover, #stringB:hover, #stringHighE:hover {
    animation:vibrate 0.1s linear 0s infinite;
    -moz-animation: vibrate 0.1s linear 0s infinite;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: vibrate 0.1s linear 0s infinite;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: vibrate 0.1s linear 0s infinite;
    /* Opera */
}
@keyframes vibrate {
    0% {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    25% {
        padding-top: -3px;
    }
    50% {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    75% {
        padding-top: 3px;
    }
    100% {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes vibrate
/* Firefox */
 {
    0% {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    25% {
        padding-top: -3px;
    }
    50% {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    75% {
        padding-top: 3px;
    }
    100% {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes vibrate
/* Safari and Chrome */
 {
    0% {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    25% {
        padding-top: -3px;
    }
    50% {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    75% {
        padding-top: 3px;
    }
    100% {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes vibrate
/* Opera */
 {
    0% {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    25% {
        padding-top: -3px;
    }
    50% {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    75% {
        padding-top: 3px;
    }
    100% {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy solution would be to set position:relative and utilize the top attribute.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4nBv/9/)

```
@keyframes vibrate {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
    }
    25% {
        top: -3px;
    }
    50% {
        top: 0px;
    }
    75% {
        top: 3px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 0px;
    }
```

To stop the animation after 3 seconds, simply let it loop 3/duration times.
[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4nBv/13/)

```
animation:vibrate 0.1s linear 0s 30;
```

Comment: Do you know how to end the animation after 3 seconds and return to original position?

Comment: since this just got upvoted, I'd like to add that 2016 you should rather do it with the css `transform` property